# PHP/HTML <option></option>

Tags: php, html, html-select

Basicly I want to make it so when I post the data to the PHP script it will use the options name="Name Here" Instead of using whats inside of `<option></option>` as the data it posts.

```
<select name="color">
  <option value="4" name="4">Dark Red</option>
  <option>Dark Blue</option>
  <option>Dark Green</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Purple</option>
</select>
```

in this code I would want it to post 4 when they pick dark red as a color then click the submit button, Anyone have any ideas? Thanks for helping!

Comment: That's exactly what would happen(because of the value attribute not the name attribute)

Comment: this would post "color=4", if they selected Dark Red

Answer (score 0):

Use just `value`, not `name`. You set `name` in the `select` element.

```
<select name="color">
  <option value="4">Dark Red</option>
  <option>Dark Blue</option>
  <option>Dark Green</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
  <option>Purple</option>
</select>
```

Upon submit, if "Dark Red" is selected, the `$_REQUEST['color']` will be `4`.

Comment: Better to be precise `$_GET`, `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` :p

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I can't get more precise, not having seen OP's `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an array on your server side. Something like

```
colors = [
    1: "Value 1",
    2: "value 2"
]
```

And then just take a

```
colors[POSTCOLOR];
```

I`m not a php master, but this is right way.